# Call specific word in string by index number?

Tags: javascript

I've been learning javascript for a solid day lol. Wondering how I can call a specific word in a string by it's count/index. An index would be desirable because the string is user input, so it could be anything.

I tried

```
const User_Input = "Some Text"
console.log(User_Input[1])
```

But that of course calls the index by letter. So the outcome was

```
"o"
```

The desired output is

```
"Text"
```

Comment: Split on spaces and then access word from the generated result by index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple to achieve using `split`

```js
const User_Input = "Some Text";

const split = User_Input.split(" ");

console.log(split);
console.log(split[1]);
```

Comment: Really interesting to see how this is done in different languages. Handy way to do it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```js
let User_Input = "Some Text"
User_Input = User_Input.split(' ')
console.log(User_Input[1])
```